# Why is my thunk not working in this fetch statement?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Trying to get my thunk working but the data is not passed in my received_data action creator:

```
const getData = () => dispatch => {
  console.log('getData called');
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json)
    .then(data => {
        dispatch(received_data(data))
      })

}
```

Why can I not get the data in my fetch? what is the issue here?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly801p34m)

Comment: By the way, I don't know why but Codesandbox's console does not work right now :) I thought it is because of your `debugger` but it does not work without it either. So, do not get confused if you don't see the logs but after those changes, your code works. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j33670qljw Also, if you open your browser's real console, you can see the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in your code. First one is in your `fetch` process.

```
.then( response => response.json )
```

This should be:

```
.then( response => response.json() )
```

Also, after getting the `users` you will have objects. So, you can't render objects directly. Of course, this is just testing, you don't want to render only `id` properties :)

Change this:

```
<div>
  This is Dumb
  <button onClick={getData}>Go</button>
  {users.map( user => <li>{user}</li> )}
</div>
```

into this:

```
<div>
  This is Dumb
  <button onClick={getData}>Go</button>
  {users.map( user => <li>{user.id}</li> )}
</div>
```